# Should I expect "device lost" conditions as normal under Vulkan?

Tags: error-handling, vulkan

I'm asking because I wonder how robust I should make my programs against device losses.

Should I only expect devices to be lost in the case of, say, hardware errors, driver bugs, improper API usage or non-terminating shader programs; or should I also expect device loss in such cases as, say, suspending and resuming my laptop, minimizing the application window, or just randomly because the implementation felt like it?

Comment: "A logical device may become lost because of hardware errors, execution timeouts, power management events and/or platform-specific events." So that's a definite maybe. It would made sense if the gpu was hot-pluggable (e.g. for the "power management" purposes).

Comment: @krOoze: Yes, I had read that part and also came to the "maybe" conclusion. It is exactly since the specification is fairly vague about it that I came here to ask.

Comment: Just FYI, a "specification" is the kind of least vague source of information, so.... Best we could do is to answer for some specific OS–HW–driver combination based on testing it.

Comment: @Dolda2000: I'm not sure I see a distinction between the first group of causes and the second group. While I don't imagine that an OS would kill a device because of minimizing a window, it's not unreasonable to assume that suspending the computer might result in loss of device. It's not clear what exactly you're trying to find out with this question.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The distinction between the first and second group would be that of exceptional events that in theory should never happen, and on the other hand totally normal events.

Comment: @Dolda2000: It should also be noted that loss of device can happen because *someone else* broke the GPU. That is, some other application did something wrong and the GPU has to be reset.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, those kinds of things are exactly what I'm wondering about. What I'm trying to evaluate is basically whether I can consider it "okay" for my program to crash if the device is lost, and such anecdotes help a lot.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Either way the app should handle it gracefully (whether it is to continue or to exit).. If you are undecided, I personally in serious app would go with trying to continue the execution. OSes already try to restart the driver themselves instead of GSOD. It is nice for the user. The code should not be much more comblex (basically `vkDestroy*` everything and do what you would do on the first (non-device-lost) execution.

Comment: @krOoze: Sure, but if it only happens on exceptional, bug-related events, then I'd be fine not caring about it.

Comment: @Dolda2000 I wouldn't worry about it for a hobby app. Just tried hibernation on W10 AMD and it does not lose the device either. Of course such info is subject to change. Only guarantees you will get is the spec quote (which allows to do device_lost for whatever purpose the OS+driver deems is a good idea to do it).

Comment: @krOoze: I do realize that I won't get any other guarantees than what the spec says. The main reason I asked the question was because I was hoping that someone with actual practical experience with some range of devices could tell what is actually happening in practice.

Comment: In theory there's no difference in theory and practice. In practice it is better to stick to the theory, lest we create platform-dependent hell. If I create my app based on the spec, I don't give a damn whether someone implements Vulkan with springs and waterwheels; it will just work anyway. I don't see how such information would be useful except for curiosity sake. Maybe add some motivation or use-case. As your question stands -- yes, you should always make robust applications for production (or die trying :p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately going to vary by GPU, driver, and OS, which leads to the somewhat vague spec wording that krOoze quoted:

> A logical device may become lost because of hardware errors, execution timeouts, power management events and/or platform-specific events.

For reference, there is nothing in the Android OS itself that would require a device lost -- e.g. it doesn't force a device-lost when an app goes into the background or the screen is turned off.

But it's likely that some driver/hardware combinations will report a device lost error if there is a GPU exception (or reset), unless the driver can guarantee that nothing from your VkDevice could have been affected. That's a surprisingly difficult guarantee to make, e.g. if your queues weren't running at the time the problem occurred, but there still might have been some of your data in dirty cache lines and the reset invalidates those lines instead of writing them back to memory, your data will be corrupted. An exception/reset can be caused by hardware or driver bugs, or by any app on the system hitting a watchdog timeout (infinite loop in shader is the easy example, but even making progress but simply taking too long can happen).

In practice, these should be fairly rare events, and I believe (without data) that these days it's primarily caused by hotplug (rare) or misbehaving hardware/driver/app events rather than more routine things like device sleep.

Since testing your recovery code is going to be difficult and it'll therefore likely be buggy, my recommendation would be to just do something heavy-handed but simple, like saving application state and either restarting your app automatically, or quitting and asking the user to restart. Depending on what you're building, it might be reasonable to do something more sophisticated like tearing down and restarting+restoring your renderer system without taking down the rest of your app.